# Creating new rows from results with ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I'm using the tables user, plan, and plan details. Where:

User:

```
public function plan_details()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Plan_Detail');
}
public function plans()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Plan');
```

Plan:

```
   public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Plan_Detail');
    }
```

I'm trying to create a new plan from an existing plan like so:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [ 'title' => 'required',
                                'description' => 'required']);
    $input = $request->all();

    $plan_details = Plan_Detail::ofUser()->get();
    $plan = new Plan($request->all());

    DB::beginTransaction();
    Auth::user()->plans()->save($plan);

    try {
      foreach ($plan_details as $k => $plan_detail)
        Plan::find($plan['id'])->details()->save($plan_detail);
      DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      Log::error("PGSQL plan detail " . $e->message());
      DB::rollback();
      session()->flash('message', 'Error al guardar el plan de entreno');
    }

    return redirect('plans');
}
```

This line does edit the plan details so no longer belong to the old plan and get into the new one:

> Plan::find($plan['id'])->details()->save($plan_detail);

I refactored the code to orm some commits ago and now I discovered this bug, I was doing all fields in an array like before save:

```
         foreach ($plan_details as $k => $plan_detail) {
+          $detail_line['exercise_id'] = $plan_detail['exercise_id'];
           $detail_line['plan_id'] = $plan['id'];
```

I wouldn't like to go back to that, but can't think of how to relation Auth::user with plan and with plan details in this way and creating new items.

If I use User->plan_details() I would need to specify which plan_id.

If I use Plan->details I have to specify user_id

Can't that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the magic method ->replicate() and it's working

```
    Plan::find($plan['id'])->details()->save( $plan_detail->replicate() );
```

---

Also, this replacing of the foreach should be an optimization in the insert queries:

```
  $replicants = [];
  foreach ($plan_details as $k => $plan_detail)
    $replicants[] = $plan_detail->replicate();

  Plan::find($plan['id'])->details()->saveMany($replicants);
```